# How to compose an email with a dataframe as a table in the body along with some text?

Tags: python, email

I want to compose an email with a table in the body along with some supporting text. So far I have:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
email_ = EmailMessage()
email_['Subject'] = "Test mail"
email_['From'] = <email_address>
email_['To'] = <email_address>
email_.set_content(df.to_html(index=False), "html")
```

How would I add some additional text underneath the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can accumulate all of the information prior to setting content :

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'col1': ['a', 'b'], 'col2': ['c', 'd']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

email_ = EmailMessage()
email_['Subject'] = "Test mail"
email_['From'] = email_address
email_['To'] = email_address

html1 = df.to_html(index=False)
html2 = df2.to_html(index=False)
two_tables_html = html1 + html2
more_text = '\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'

body_text = two_tables_html + more_text

email_.set_content(body_text, "html")

print(email_)
```

Comment: This is great thanks. However the `'\n'` doesn't seem to add a new line?

Comment: if the display in is html, to add a blank line, you can add <br>  (and you can look in a reference for HTML tags for additional text control commands)